# Ways of adding new methods to an interface not affecting the existing sub classes of this interface in java6?

Tags: java

Sometime back I faced a situation to add a method in one interface which was already used by 15+ classes. At the time of implementation, the old classes not required of this new method, but this new method is required for other new classes. Here, need to consider is, this new method is optional for old classes and mandatory for newly developing classes.
What are the ways to solve this issue?

I have solved like the following way:
I have created a new interface and declare a method in this interface and implement it with old interface in new classes and will do the same for other old classes if they require this new method.

Java8, we have a "default to handle this type of situations, but what are the other ways to solve this type of situation in older versions of Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older versions of Java didn't have any way to solve this problem. That's why default methods were introduced in Java 8.

Note that the JVM will happily load a class implementing an interface even if it doesn't actually implement all its methods (i.e. if it was compiled before new methods were added): you'll only have an exception at runtime, when calling one of these unimplemented methods.

That's why old JDBC drivers still work in newer JREs, even though they don't implement all the new JDBC methods... unless of course you call one of these new methods.

Comment: Yes. I agree. Older versions don't have a solution directly and If we run the class with already compiled class it will run without error even after adding a new method in that interface, but we can't go further with this implementation. It may be failed during regression or integration testing, or due to the subclasses extend this class and they need to be compiled kind of situation, etc. Any workaround like what i have mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

For this you write one new interface and make it child of old interface declare new method in it now create new class and make it child of existing class and implements new created interface and diffine your new method here now where you want extra method change old interface with new declare interface ie child interface and pass object of child class now you can call your new method as well old method it will also not effect other class implementation